# How to set Static selected item in the middle of Horizontal RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to make my RecyclerView like this to display holidays in my app. Here the current date to be highlighted.And always it should be in the middle. And even,If the Date is January 1,it is also has to be started at the middle. Can I do it by using Recycler View? If yes,how to do this? Please help me.

Even I listed the date in RecyclerView. Just I need to highlight it and make the current date in the middle with highlighted background.

Your answer is more appreciated.

[image]

Comment: use ViewPager to show date...

Comment: Even I listed the date in RecyclerView. Just I need to highlight it and make the current date in the middle  with highlighted background.

Comment: can you provide code what you have tried ?

Comment: wow good luck with that ...

Comment: I have achieved the things by referring the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586637/get-center-visible-item-of-recycleview-when-scrolling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117916/android-centering-item-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

you can make this layout by using recyclerview. In my case, I will create this layout by using framelayout and recyclerview. just wrap recyclerview with framelayout and float rectangle view is filled by white color.