# Horizontally center first item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I want to use a `RecyclerView` to emulate the behavior of a `MultiViewPager`, in particular I'd like to have the selected item at the center of the screen, **including the first and the last element**.

As you can see in this image, the first item is centered and this would be my expected result.
[image: Expected result]

What I did was to setup a `RecyclerView` with an horizontal `LinearLayoutManager` and a `LinearSnapHelper`. The problem with this solution is that the first and the last item will never be horizontally centered as selection. Should I switch my code so that it uses a `MultiViewPager` or is it possible to achieve a similar result taking advantage of a `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implement this with an `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` in [`getItemOffsets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#getItemOffsets(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.view.View,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)), to offset the first and last item appropriately.

> Retrieve any offsets for the given item. Each field of `outRect` specifies the number of pixels that the item view should be inset by, similar to padding or margin. The default implementation sets the bounds of outRect to 0 and returns.
>
> If you need to access Adapter for additional data, you can call [`getChildAdapterPosition(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getChildAdapterPosition(android.view.View)) to get the adapter position of the View.

You might need to use the messured size of the item and the `RecyclerView` as well. But these information is available to be used anyhow.

Comment: This seems to me the proper way to go, the suggestion in the other answer by @CzarMatt might work but it seems a bit hacky to me.

Comment: @Vektor88, usage of `decoration` is not that good as it seems to be. I did it that way, but it break a lot of `RecyclerView` rules, because `decoration`s are intended to be an extension of the item. It means left/right offsets for centering will be handled as it was real view `padding/margin`, so it's `LayoutManager.getDecoratedMeasuredWidth()` will be really big. It will break, e.g., `LinearSnapHelper`. First/Last element will be snaped to next/prev on even slight touches, because they think your view is hude.

Comment: @Vektor88, this is much more preferable way to go - https://stackoverflow.com/q/29117916/2653714

Comment: @Nexen the approach you suggested is much better than this, and also solves my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766186/linearsnaphelper-doesnt-snap-on-edge-items-of-recyclerview

Comment: @Vektor88, glad to hear! Well then I will post this as an answer there

Answer (score 5):

I ended up with this implementation in my project. You can pass different dimension in constructor to set the spacing between the items. As I wrote in the class' KDoc, it will add `(total parent space - child width) / 2` to the left of first and to the right of last item in order to center first and last items.

```
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.DimenRes
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.OrientationHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

/**
 * Adds (total parent space - child width) / 2 to the left of first and to the right of last item (in order to center first and last items),
 * and [spacing] between items.
 */
internal class OffsetItemDecoration constructor(
    @DimenRes private val spacing: Int,
) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State,
    ) {
        val itemPosition: Int = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        if (itemPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return

        val spacingPixelSize: Int = parent.context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(spacing)

        when (itemPosition) {
            0 ->
                outRect.set(getOffsetPixelSize(parent, view), 0, spacingPixelSize / 2, 0)
            parent.adapter!!.itemCount - 1 ->
                outRect.set(spacingPixelSize / 2, 0, getOffsetPixelSize(parent, view), 0)
            else ->
                outRect.set(spacingPixelSize / 2, 0, spacingPixelSize / 2, 0)
        }
    }

    private fun getOffsetPixelSize(parent: RecyclerView, view: View): Int {
        val orientationHelper = OrientationHelper.createHorizontalHelper(parent.layoutManager)
        return (orientationHelper.totalSpace - view.layoutParams.width) / 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for any future wanderers, here is the usage:
`binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(OffsetItemDecoration(R.dimen.item_spacing))` 

(you can use either binding or `findViewById`, doesn't matter)  

note that you will need to make a dimension `item_spacing` in your `res/values/dimens.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

Just add padding on `RecyclerView` and  add `clipToPadding=false` and it'll only affect the items on the ends.

Comment: Genius. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: what padding will you use? there are lots of different screen sizes and one padding won't make the item centered in all of them.

Comment: @MustafaBerkayMutlu You can implement it programmatically. As you mentioned there are lots of screen sizes, we can use DisplayMetrics to get the screen width, then we can use LayoutParams to set the left/right padding of the RecyclerView to half of the screen width, just my ideas here.

Comment: @marticztn I just posted the implementation I ended up using below https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791829/2708768

Answer (score 3):

> The problem with this solution is that the first and the last item
>   will never be horizontally centered as selection.

This is probably because your RecycleView is responsible for showing, within its layout bounds, exactly the number of items that are inside of your data set.

In the example image you provided, you can achieve that effect by adding a "placeholder" item in the first and last position of your dataset.  This way, you can have an invisible item taking up the first slot, thus offsetting the item you want to be centered.

This placeholder item should not respond to touch events and should not interfere with handling of click events on other items (specifically, the position handling).

You will have to modify your adapters `getItemCount` and perhaps `getItemType`.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on @I.S answer which works 100% of the time and is very easy to implement without any glitchy animation. First we have to use `PagerSnapHelper()` to have view pager like scroll. To center the items you need to add a large padding on the recyclerView and then clip to the padding. Then use a customized `LinearSmoothScroller` to smoothly center your item. To center the item on load, just use smooth scroll to position 0. Below is the code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_selection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="150dp"
        android:paddingRight="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_selection_alert"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_stat"/>
```

And in Code (in C#)

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(Context, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false);

recycler_selection = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recycler_selection);
recycler_selection.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Context, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false));
// <Set Adapter to the Recycler>

RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new CenterScroller(recycler_selection.Context);

SnapHelper helper = new PagerSnapHelper();
helper.AttachToRecyclerView(recycler_selection);

smoothScroller.TargetPosition = 0;
lm.StartSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);

public class CenterScroller : LinearSmoothScroller
    {
        float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 350f;

        public CenterScroller(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public override int CalculateDtToFit(int viewStart, int viewEnd, int boxStart, int boxEnd, int snapPreference)
        {
            return (boxStart + (boxEnd - boxStart) / 2) - (viewStart + (viewEnd - viewStart) / 2);
        }

        protected override float CalculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
        {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.Xdpi;
        }
    }
```