# Horizontal RecyclerView - list items arranged from center

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to show the items of a horizontal recyclerview aligned in center.
i.e. the gravity of the list will be center_horizontal.

For example, to implement something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `layout_gravity=center` for Horizontal Recycler view itself?

Comment: @Khamraj Hi, my idea was to fill the width, but I guess this should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to define your custom layout manager:
[Android Centering Item in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117916/android-centering-item-in-recyclerview)

Or if you need to get discrete scrolling here's the lib: 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5480

Or recyclerView could be `wrap_content` with center aligment in parent frame:
[How do I make WRAP_CONTENT work on a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```